# Ubuntu with cc1plus - error Not Implemented

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, g++, rdkit

I am trying to use the `make` command on Ubuntu 11.10, but get an error.

> g++ -g -O2 -fPIC -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wendif-labels -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -fpic -Wno-deprecated -Wno-unused-function -I/usr/local/include -I/home/jochen/RDKit/Code -DRDKITVER='"004000"'  -I/usr/local/include -I/home/jochen/RDKit/Code -DRDKITVER='"004000"'  -I. -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/include/tcl8.5  -c -o adapter.o adapter.cpp
>
> cc1plus: nicht implementiert: -fexcess-precision=standard for C++
>   make: *** [adapter.o] Fehler 1

I have installed GCC, G++, and the build-essentials.

Output from `gcc -v`:

> Es werden eingebaute Spezifikationen verwendet.
>   COLLECT_GCC=g++
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/lto-wrapper
>   Ziel: i686-linux-gnu
>   Konfiguriert mit: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,go --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
>   Thread-Modell: posix
>   gcc-Version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)

How can this be fixed?

Comment: @p.campbell looks like it says "not implemented" in German

Comment: The flag `-fexcess-precision` is only supported in [GCC 4.5 or later](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html). Which version of gcc do you have? You can type `gcc --version` at a terminal to find out. I thought Ubuntu 11.10 had 4.6?

Comment: Workaround: don't use -fexcess-precision=standard if it's not implemented

Comment: gcc and g++ are both 4.6.1...i can't edit the file which will execute this command...i only do make in an directory and this is the output

Comment: @bladepit can you post `g++ -v` output?

Comment: i hope its ok...some words in german...

Comment: Es werden eingebaute Spezifikationen verwendet.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/lto-wrapper

Comment: Ziel: i686-linux-gnu
Konfiguriert mit: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,go --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --

Comment: libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread-Modell: posix
gcc-Version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)

Comment: @bladepit You might want to just edit the original question with the information instead.  Does your makefile by chance override the version used?

Comment: doesn't look like....should i paste it in my post...:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc implements the `-fexcess-precision` option, but *only* for C.

The documentation for the option can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) (search for `-fexcess-precision`) (this is the gcc 4.6.3 manual):

> `-fexcess-precision=`*style*
>
> This option allows further control over excess precision on machines
>   where floating-point registers have more precision than the IEEE
>   `float` and `double` types and the processor does not support
>   operations rounding to those types.
>
> *[SNIP]*
>
> `-fexcess-precision=standard` is not implemented for languages other
>   than C, and has no effect if `-funsafe-math-optimizations` or
>   `-ffast-math` is specified. On the x86, it also has no effect if
>   `-mfpmath=sse` or `-mfpmath=sse+387` is specified; in the former case,
>   IEEE semantics apply without excess precision, and in the latter,
>   rounding is unpredictable.

You've told us that (a) you're compiling C++, (b) your script or `Makefile` uses `-fexcess-precision`, and (c) you can't change it.  One of those has got to give.  You have a bug in your script or `Makefile`, and you need to fix it.

Note that gcc probably *should* implement `-fexcess-precision=standard` for C++; as far as I know, C++ rules in this area are the same as C's and C requires this behavior for standard conformance.  It's possible that your code depends on the behavior specified by `-fexcess-precision=standard`, and that gcc just doesn't support it.  If that's the case, you've got a problem; it may be that the only way to work around it would be to make major modifications to your C++ source code.  Or it may be that it implements the right behavior for C++; the manual isn't 100% clear on that point.

There is another possible workaround.  You could write your own wrapper for the `g++` command that invokes the real `g++` command after deleting any occurrences of `-fexcess-precision` from its command line arguments.  I've done [something similar](http://users.sdsc.edu/~kst/gcc-wrapper/) in the past, for a slightly different situation; you'd have to hack it to modify command-line arguments rather than filtering `stderr`.  But I *do not* recommend this.  The right solution is to fix the build script or `Makefile` -- assuming, again, that the program doesn't depend on the behavior specified by `-fexcess-precision=standard`.